# Listing or getting permissions assigned to the folders under Shared Drive

Tags: google-drive-api

I am trying to list all permissions assigned to files/folders under the shared drive for the purpose of retrieving external collaborators.

It seems I have proper access right for All the files and folders since I can list/get them via drive API, but when it comes the the permission, the API claims the file/folders do not exist.
Is this the known behavior, or there is another way of retrieving permissions from files/folders in the shared drive?

## request and response

- request
  `GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/[FILE ID]/permissions?useDomainAdminAccess=true&key=[YOUR_API_KEY] HTTP/1.1`
- response

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "notFound",
    "message": "File not found: [FILE ID].",
    "locationType": "parameter",
    "location": "fileId"
   }
  ],
  "code": 404,
  "message": "File not found: [FILE ID]."
 }
}
```

Comment: try doing a file.list first to ensure that you are using a file id that you have acccess to.

Comment: Thanks. I just did and confirmed I had an access.

Comment: useDomainAdminAccess=true  what happens if you remove that?

Comment: doesn't really change

[edit]
`GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/[FILE ID]/permissions?key=[YOUR_API_KEY] HTTP/1.1`

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "notFound",
    "message": "File not found:[FILE ID].",
    "locationType": "parameter",
    "location": "fileId"
   }
  ],
  "code": 404,
  "message": "File not found: [FILE ID]."
 }
}
```

Comment: is the user you are authorized as owner of this file?

Comment: yes. the user is authorized as owner (and even has google drive owner)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Answer:

*You need to make your request with `useDomainAdminAccess` set to `false` and `supportsAllDrives` set to `true`.*

#### Example Request:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/[FILE_ID]/permissions?supportsAllDrives=true&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]
```

Comment: Thanks, I think I understood the behavior. 
If you are the member of drive, then `useDomainAdminAccess` must be `false` to get permissions; but if you aren't, then `useDomainAdminAccess` must be `true`.  Weird behavior, but, thanks!